# Detectar se a pasta ou arquivo é oculto ou não no Windows com PHP

Tags: php, windows

Estou listando diretórios do Windows com o `scandir()` do `PHP`, desse jeito mostra todos os itens do local, e gostaria de saber se é possível verificar se a pasta ou arquivo exibido pelo `PHP` está oculta no Windows.

Comment: Se quer esta informação, qual seria o motivo de ter escolhido justo o `scandir`?

Comment: porque uso o array dela para retornar com json para outra pagina

Comment: Existe uma forma de fazer sem o `scandir`, veja nessa discussão https://stackoverflow.com/a/28681410/10304819

Comment: @AndréLins essa foi uma das coisas mais nojentas que eu ja vi na minha vida :D , usar comandos do sistema operacional para obter a informação. Não é portátil, não é seguro e ainda é desabilitado em qualquer hospedagem minimamente decente.

Comment: @AndréLins ainda quero que o array tenha a pastas e arquivos ocultas, mas que adicione junto a elas uma variável apontando se é oculta ou não, pra isso apenas preciso saber de um modo se é ou não, o resto eu dou um jeito kkk

Comment: Nunca utilizei, mas já tinha visto em alguns lugares, por isso trouxe a opção kkk. Como é tão ruim seria interessante mencionar isso lá e o no comentário do php. :D

Comment: @AndréLins ah sim, trazer o link é sempre bom, mas que é feio, é :D - Mas como se trata de PHP, muitas vezes só tem jeito feio de fazer certas coisas - espero que surja alguma resposta aqui que fique "menos feia", se é que existe. Não me lembro de nada específico do PHP para ler atributos deste tipo.

Comment: No rol das soluções nojentas tem essa tb: `exec("dir \"{$path}\" /A:-H /B", $result);` (alternando o `-H` por `H` para pegar os não ocultos e os ocultos separadamente).